# QGIS: regular points tool numbering

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules

I've made a regular grid and regular points for a grid, I want to set this inside of a boundary so I have deleted the points outside the boundary. However, when I do this the ID still shows up counting the deleted point. I want the visible points to start with and ID of 1 or 0.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could update the attribute containing your ID via the **Field Calculator** and using the expression:

```
$rownum
```

This should reset your points to starting from 1. Remember to save the edits.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @PeterB - Most welcome buddy! Glad you got it sorted =)